# Put a check for the incoming param as object

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components, json

I need some quick help i have to put a check in my javascript for an incoming parameter is a JSON Object.

```
if (objecttest is json then only it should go inside) {
}
checkFor(objecttest , data) {
}
```

Comment: See if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3710204/how-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-json-string-in-javascript-without-using-try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON in javascript can be treated as Object. So if the `string` is parsable then its a `JSON`, otherwise not.

So you can create a method :

```
function checkIfJSON(strJSONString){
    try{
        JSON.parse(strJSONString);
        return true;
    } catch(e){
        return false;
    }
}
```

And then call that like this : `checkIfJSON('[{}]');`